# How can I apply my custom validation on a ui-grid cell template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there a way to bind custom validation. I would like to bind a method on say ng-keydown to check the input against my set of rules.. How can that be done. I trying calling a $scope function on ng-change and that didn't work.

I tried this `ng-change="grid.appScope.checkValidaton($event,MODEL_COL_FIE‌​LD,true,true)`. The scope function gets called however the arguments are undefined. How can I pass the $event and ng-model along.

And this is my column:

```
{ name: "group", editableCellTemplate:
                "<div><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\"  ng-change=\"grid.appScope.checkValidaton($event,MODEL_COL_FIELD,true,true)\"></div>", displayName: "Group", enableCellEdit: true, showSortMenu: false, cellTooltip: true
                },
```

I had my reference from : http://plnkr.co/edit/4Pvc4UYKSf71pIC2XrpY?p=preview

Comment: Would it work for you if the validation check occurred on the cell losing focus, or does it need to be on every keydown?

Comment: it needs to be on real time on key down...Basically I have to prevent inputting. Else I could have used `.on.afterEdit`

Comment: OK. I don't have a solution for that case myself. Hope someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of searching over internet and reading about ui-grid events, I coded a directive to use the `scope` entity and ui-grid events to apply validation on click of cell.

The basic trick was to use the custom editable template and apply validation on its field.

Here is the code, it can also be found at my repository [here](https://github.com/soyiatgit/CodedUtilities/blob/master/uiGridValidationDirective.js)

```
(function(module){

    module.directive('gridValidation', gridValidationFn);

    gridValidationFn.$inject = ['uiGridEditConstants'];

    function gridValidationFn(uiGridEditConstants) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="txtValue"  ng-change="changeTxt(txtValue)"/></div>',
            scope: true,
            link: gridValidationLinkFn
        };

        return directive;

        function gridValidationLinkFn(scope, elm, attr) {

            var oldTxt = scope.row.entity[scope.col.field];
            scope.limit = attr.limit;
            scope.txtValue = oldTxt;

            function windowClickListener(ev) {
                if (ev.target.nodeName !== "INPUT")
                    scope.editDone();
            }

            scope.changeTxt = function (val) {
                if (attr.words) {
                    if (scope.txtValue && scope.txtValue.match(/\S+/g) && scope.txtValue.match(/\S+/g).length > Number(scope.limit)) {
                        scope.txtValue = scope.txtValue.split(/\s+/, Number(scope.limit)).join(" ");
                        scope.row.entity[scope.col.field] = scope.txtValue.split(/\s+/, Number(scope.limit)).join(" ");
                    }
                    else
                        scope.row.entity[scope.col.field] = scope.txtValue;
                }
                else {
                    if (scope.txtValue && scope.txtValue.length > Number(scope.limit)) {
                        scope.txtValue = scope.txtValue.slice(0, Number(scope.limit));
                        scope.row.entity[scope.col.field] = scope.txtValue;
                    }
                    else
                        scope.row.entity[scope.col.field] = scope.txtValue;
                }
            };

            scope.editDone = function () {
                scope.$emit(uiGridEditConstants.events.END_CELL_EDIT);
            };

            scope.$on(uiGridEditConstants.events.BEGIN_CELL_EDIT, function () {
                angular.element(window).on('click', windowClickListener);
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                angular.element(window).off('click', windowClickListener);
            });
        }

    }
}(angular.module("ModuleName")));
```

It works nicely for me. Hope it helps someone else